# How to delete specific lines from a CSV file based on line number in beanshell scripting

Tags: jmeter, beanshell

Currently, I am trying to remove a specific line from a CSV file based on the line number.

Suppose I have a CSV file having below data:

```
Rakesh,1000,25,M
Gopi,2000,26,M
Shiva,3000,30,M
Gopi,5500,29,M
Tiru,4400,30,M
Ravi,3020,20,M
```

Also, I have an array which consists of some random number `[2,5,6]`

So instated of reading the entire file and writing it again I want to go to that specific line and remove that line completely.

```
Rakesh,1000,25,M
Shiva,3000,30,M
Gopi,5500,29,M
```

Code

```
 String fileData = FileUtils.readFileToString(csvFile);
    int lines = FileUtils.readLines(csvFile).size();
    log.info("Size:"+lines);
    ArrayList myList = new ArrayList();
    for (int i=1; i<lines; i++) {
                myList.add(i);
    }
    Collections.shuffle(myList);
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
      log.info("Numebr:"+myList.get(i));
    }

    // Need to the line delete include that logic.

    FileUtils.writeStringToFile(output, fileData);
```

Comment: Anyone have answer for this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all [Forget about Beanshell](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/is-beanshell-dead/).

[Since JMeter 3.1 you should be using JSR223 test elements and Groovy language](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) for scripting.

The relevant [Groovy](https://groovy-lang.org/) script which removes the lines from the original file basing on the array of 1-based line numbers provided would be something like:

```
def file = new File('test.csv')
def originalLines = file.readLines()
def array = [2, 5, 6]
def newLines = []
0.upto(originalLines.size() - 1, { index ->
    if (!array.contains(index + 1)) {
        newLines.add(originalLines.get(index))
    } else {
        array.removeElement(index)
    }
})
file.withWriter { w ->
    newLines.each { w.println it }
}
```

Demo:

[image]

Comment: So we need to write the entire file again?  We cant open the file and go to the line number and delete it?

Comment: Thanks for the script. I want to migrate my existing BeanShell script, do we have any code converter for BeanShell to Groovy?